# Xpath writing for one element which doesn't have any unique id

Tags: java, ios, xpath, appium

Currently in my application accessibility id is not implemented for elements and I am facing challenges in locating the xpath.
Using properties how can I write the xpath?
I am using appium studio on windows to automate an iOS app.

I written some xpath,which is not working.

```
       (//*[@class='UIATabBar']/*[@class='UIAButton'])[2]
```

for 2nd image the xpath is

```
        //*[@class='UIAView' and ./*[@id='2Test WebApp']]
```

If I want to iterate using for loop, not getting xpath,where changing the value I can iterate in the list.

This xpath is suggested by appium studio itself,but it is not working.and not able to write unique xpath.
Attached the image as well to get clear idea.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this. you are trying to get the 2nd button.

```
(//*[@class='UIATabBar']/*[@class='UIAButton'][2])
```

For the 2nd one.

```
//*[@class='UIAView'][*[@id='2Test WebApp']]
```

Comment: Please ask another question

Comment: not allowing me to post now, I can post only in 90 minutes. it is kind of urgent.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is there any other way to write the xpath of the 2nd image , if I dont want [@id='2Test WebApp'], what else I can write in place of it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199043/discussion-between-tester-and-metal).